# Could not find layout engine view for view's -Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am a  xamarin  developer,  I  am using visual studio xamarin   and  using a virtual MAC machine in  my windows machine for build and deployment. Today I have updated the Xamarin to Xamarin 3.
Now I am facing an issue.
I am able connect  Xamarin iOS Build Host.
But the  issue is, when I try to run the application, I am getting “deployment errors” message.

Error description is as follows.

```
1>Build server returned an Error.
1>2014-05-29 15:12:31.338 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[367:303] 
1>WARNING: 
1>Reason:     Could not find layout engine view for view's (<UILabel: 0x18ec1b90; frame = (5 0; 20 20); text = '31'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x18eafcd0>>) coordinate space view <UIView: 0xb6515a0; frame = (0 0; 50 65); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x18ee7ca0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x18ec9cd0>>. But the canvas coordinateSpaceView is view's superview, so we are assuming the same in the layout engine.
1>File:       /SourceCache/IBAutolayoutFoundationIOS/IBAutolayoutFoundation-3430/Framework/Classes/Arbitration/IBAutolayoutEngine.m:335
1>Method:     -[IBAutolayoutEngine layoutFrameForView:inCoordinateSpaceOfView:]
```

Please let me know ,if you have any idea regarding this issue..